# Android App with PhoneGap: InvocationTarget Exception by calling addJavascriptInterface

Tags: android, cordova

I am using the Android SDK and PhoneGap to create a native Android App. Now I want to use Java methods in the view, calling by JS methods.

In the Main Class I called the "addJavascriptInterface" method to bind a java class with the view.

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");        

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

The problem is I get an InvocationTarget Exception when the programm executes the line "appView.addJavascript..." and the program crashes on the device.

Any solutions here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Calling Java methods from JavaScript is exactly what PhoneGap plugins enable. Checkout several examples [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android)

Answer (score 1):

Using addJavascriptInterface before super.init(); can make the application crash.

You should try the following :

```
public class App extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.init();

        appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");        

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```